# jQuery Dropdown Menu Doesn't Stay Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I've created a dropdown menu in a site built on Wordpress. It works, but there's a problem; when the mouse hovers over the menu items, the dropdown menu keeps sliding up and down.

HTML

```
<nav>
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-20"><a href="http://s386670101.websitehome.co.uk/us/?page_id=10">Art Services</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-93" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-93"><a href="http://s386670101.websitehome.co.uk/us/?page_id=86">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-92"><a href="http://s386670101.websitehome.co.uk/us/?page_id=88">Business</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>     
</nav>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".menu-item").hover(function() { //When trigger is clicked...

    //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
    $(this).find(".sub-menu").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click

    $(this).hover(function() {
    }, function(){  
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
    });

    //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
    }).hover(function() { 
        $(this).addClass("subhover").css('display','block'); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
    }, function(){  //On Hover Out
        $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
});
 });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `".sub-menu"` list is nested inside the `'menu-item'`, right? So you don't need a to trigger another `hover()` event. You can trim it down to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu-item").hover(function () {
        //HOVER IN
        $(this).addClass("subhover");
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").stop().slideDown('fast');
    }, function () {
        //HOVER OUT
        $(this).removeClass("subhover");
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").stop().slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

And add [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop extra running animation when user hover's in and out.

See demo here: [jsfiddle.net/AbkXM/](http://jsfiddle.net/AbkXM/)

Comment: can you replicate the whole menu in jsfiddle.net. I think there is something about your CSS as well that we should know.